# Connect to different databases using LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I need write simple util, which will connect to different databases. It'll be good to use LINQ. How can I create custom connection using LINQ? 
For example, there'll be form with 4 textboxes: server, database name, login and password. And I need create connection string with this params.

I know how can I do it via ADO, but I need use LINQ.

P.S. LINQ to SQL.

Comment: LinqToAnythingInparticular? LinqToSQL or LinqToEntities comes to mind.

Comment: LINQ to SQL. Thanks for your remark

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but this may be related to what you want; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068944/linq-to-sql-connectionstring

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to build a connection string from your inputs and then pass that to the constructor of your DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlConnectionStringBuilder performs checks for valid key/value pairs. Therefore, you cannot use this class to create invalid connection strings; trying to add invalid pairs will throw an exception. The class maintains a fixed collection of synonyms and can translate from a synonym to the corresponding well-known key name.